# Running Qt app outside CodeXL works fine, but in CodeXL it crashes

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, crash, codexl

My Qt app crashes when ran in the CodeXL debugger under Linux (Ubuntu), why might that that be?

When it crashes, the top stack frame is selected, with the message "raise.c was not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the crash in [this post on the AMD forum](https://community.amd.com/thread/189260#2675034). But the fix there seems outdated in terms of where to go in the CodeXL UI.

The fix that worked for me:

CodeXL -> File -> Project Settings -> General -> Environment variables -> "...". There add an env var with name `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and value - the path where your Qt `.so` files reside. For me that path was `/home/stefan/software/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/lib`.

*Note:* The same fix works in Windows, but there you should use `PATH` env var and not the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` one.